# Is CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM enough unique?

Tags: sql-server, uniqueidentifier

I am generating a token using something this

```
SET @Token = CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

The token will be visible in the URL and should be unique.

Is a good idea use it?

Comment: Good idea is pretty broad. The only real question you have posed is will it be unique.

Comment: The problem I see here is that you're not controlling the type of the GUID. Only type 4 guids should be randomly generated yet your values could claim to be of other types and so generate a collision with a value already used. In other words - it's fine to generate 16 random bytes. It's not, generally, fine to cast that result to GUID/uniqueidentifier which carries additional semantics.

Comment: That will *not* get you a valid GUID. In particular, the "type" bits of the GUID will be filled randomly. If you want 16 random bytes that are secure, then get 16 random bytes, but don't pretend they're a GUID. Just pass the token as a hexstring so there's no confusion (`CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16), 2)`). The problem with pretending it's a GUID is that inevitably, someone *will* actually use `NEWID()` somewhere, thinking that it's OK, since GUIDs aren't expected to be secure. Use the proper type for the occasion.

Comment: if you want a GUID that is both random and unique, and you don't mind it if generating one takes a little longer than with `NEWID()`, you can still use `CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM()` to produce the random bits and set the "type" and "version" bits correctly afterward. That would give you 122 bits of cryptographic security, which is probably enough.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, what do you mean with setting the "type" and "version" bit correclty afteward?

Comment: GUIDs have *structure*. Read [RFC 4122](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4122) for the gory details. If you don't want or *need* that structure, use 16 bytes but *don't* cast to `uniqueidentifier`/`guid` and claim structure that you're not actually adhering to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "GUID" you produce this way is not a true GUID, because the bits in the GUID reserved to indicate the variant and version of the GUID will also be random. In practice, most tools don't care about or look at the bits of a GUID at all, but it is just about conceivable that some system or future version *will* have a problem with a GUID bit pattern that isn't valid. A collision is not something you have to fear, given that the remaining bits are random on your end, but this is still ugly.

For (cryptographically) random GUIDs, you want a GUID with version 4, variant 1. Four bits indicate the version and two indicate variant 1, leaving 122 random bits, which should be plenty. Setting these bits correctly in T-SQL is not intuitive, but doable:

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(7) + 
    -- Set version = 4
    CONVERT(BINARY(1), (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 15) | 64) +
    -- Set variant = 1
    CONVERT(BINARY(1), (CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(1) & 63) | 128) +
    CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(7) 
)
```

The position of the bits and the bytes is not intuitive, because SQL Server's encoding for them is [weird](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121869/sql-server-uniqueidentifier-guid-internal-representation).

Also consider the following alternatives:

1. Use plain [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql) for a token where there is little to no concern that an attacker might guess the next value, or security will not be compromised if they do. Remember, this typically requires at least the ability to generate a block of GUIDs at will, and at worst access to the memory of the machine generating the GUIDs. The former can be rate limited and the latter means it's probably game over anyway.
2. Use random bytes with no pretense that it is a GUID and convert these to a hexstring, as obtained by (for example) `SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(32), CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(16), 2)` (convert back with `SELECT CONVERT(BINARY(16), @s, 2)`). A string is even easier to pass around than a GUID, so it's hard to see why you'd absolutely need a GUID here. You also get 6 whole bits of randomness back. A `BINARY(16)` column is the same size as `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, so storage is not the issue either. (But you may wish to consider using a string column anyway, to leave open room for new token formats in the future.)